# How fast can you ruin a Scrabble game?

Tags: letters, scrabble

Consider a standard game of Scrabble® using the csw19 dictionary.

Many board-states exist where ZERO possible next moves exist. That is, no combination of 1-7 remaining letters can make a legal move.

My question is, how **fast** can you legally get the board into this state?  I have a solution with an answer of **FOUR** moves, and will award the check to the first to provide one such solution.

*Note: Better solutions may exist.*

HINTS:

- The 'players' obviously will not be playing intelligently or even *logically*, just legally.
- The moves may take certain tiles out of play that would have been the only way to make a valid word later

Comment: The tag excerpt for [[tag:open-ended]] starts with "OPEN-ENDED PUZZLES ARE NO LONGER IN SCOPE." - i.e. off-topic. See [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) for why. If a provable optimum exists, then [[tag:optimization]] would work.

Comment: I am asking for a particular solution.  The puzzle itself is NOT open ended.  I added the tag because optimizing the solution may be of interest to some people as an additional exercise.  I'll remove the tag, but you're being pedantic.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation I wouldn't say it's pedantic. Part of moderation is ensuring that users are following site guidelines. If your puzzle isn't open ended, then don't use the open ended tag. As you and bobble both pointed out, the optimization tag is a better fit.

Comment: @TwoBitOperation correctly tagging questions is an important part of curating the site. This isn't open ended, and bobble helpfully provided an alternative.

Comment: Rather frustratingly, I can do it in five (and almost four if only "vy" was a word).

Comment: I guess my gripe stemmed from the fact that so often a puzzle posted here and the discussion immediately goes meta:  Was it posted the right way? Can I find a duplicate? Etc.  Anyway, I suppose that's the internet, and it is a very fine moderation line to walk.  And, all things considered I came across as way more a jerk than I intended to, so sorry about that.  Back to puzzling.

Comment: Is this relevant? Looks like 4 moves in the "Kyle Corbin" solution but I don't know if the dictionary has changed in the last 8 years.  https://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames/comments/1le3x3/can_2_words_finish_a_scrabble_game/

Comment: @Amoz That seems very relevant!  And it answers my question as to whether you can do less than 4.  I'd have to accept that answer as correct here, but in the spirit of things I hope someone finds one on their own.  My answer is different than Corbin's.  I've done extensive testing to make sure there's no valid moves on my answer but I have to admit I'm worried I've somehow missed something given the complexity.

Comment: *Thought* I had one, but I forgot to take into account tile counts.

Comment: @TacoタコスI saw your answer before it was deleted; tile counts were fine because you had blanks to work with, but one of your words could be added to with an 'es'

Comment: If you’re allowed to only ruin the game for one player (i.e. the other player can keep up to 7 tiles on their rack), then there’s a solution in 2 turns. Player 1 plays VAV then player 2 plays vAv keeping KSSSS. Player 1 now has no moves. [Source: Mack Meller](https://youtube.com/shorts/YSc6pPwj_zg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this succession of plays:

> h6 QAT; 7g qAT; 8h (T)Ix/(T)I; 9i XU/(TI)X/(x)U

producing a grid

> ```
> .Q..
> qAT.
> .TIX
> ..xU
> ```

Comment: This looks good; give me a little time to try to find a play, but I can't see one at the moment!  Great answer!

Comment: If there's a play I can't find it.  Nice work!  I'll post my answer for comparison.

Answer (score 3):

**Please UPVOTE @Rosie F's Answer**

---

The 4 move solution I found when designing the question:

> 1) GIBUS across
> 2) (Q)IS down
> 3) SU(Q) down
> 4) GIBUS down
> [image: 4 Move Solution]
> The only acceptable move is 'gibuses' which cannot be played since no **blank** or **S** remains.

Comment: Forgive my possible shortsightedness here, but where are the two blanks used? I see one for the second 'Q', but where is the second blank played in this grid? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't really clear.  The main point is that both blanks are both used somewhere other than the S's.  I had them on both Q's, and have updated the picture to show.

Comment: Ah, okay gotcha - so the blanks have both been used in place of other tiles which are still available in the bag but which were not drawn by the players in the course of this game. Got it :)